# Conditionally Reducing Javascript Arrays by date

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reduce

I have an array of events which contain an ISO-8601 date and a string that details the type of event:

```
0: {date: "2023-01-11T18:00:00+00:00", type: "Meeting"}
1: {date: "2023-01-12T13:00:00+00:00", type: "Lunch"}
2: {date: "2023-01-12T13:00:00+00:00", type: "Meeting"}
3: {date: "2023-01-13T09:00:00+00:00", type: "Phonecall"}
4: {date: "2023-01-13T09:00:00+00:00", type: "Breakfast"}
5: {date: "2023-01-13T09:00:00+00:00", type: "Meeting"}
```

I am using the following script to group these by ISO-8601 date:

```
events.reduce((time, event) => {
  const date = event.date;
  if (!time[date]) {
    time[date] = [];
  }
  time[date].push(event);

  return time;
}, {});
```

This is working well however I'd like to adapt this code to add some conditional logic that states to only group the events if there are more than two where the ISO-8601 date is the same.

So, using the example above it would group them as:

```
2023-01-11T18:00:00+00:00:
0: {date: "2023-01-11T18:00:00+00:00", type: "Meeting"}

2023-01-12T13:00:00+00:00:
0: {date: "2023-01-12T13:00:00+00:00", type: "Lunch"}

2023-01-12T13:00:00+00:00:
0: {date: "2023-01-12T13:00:00+00:00", type: "Meeting"}

2023-01-13T09:00:00+00:00:
0: {date: "2023-01-13T09:00:00+00:00", type: "Phonecall"}
1: {date: "2023-01-13T09:00:00+00:00", type: "Breakfast"}
2: {date: "2023-01-13T09:00:00+00:00", type: "Meeting"}
```

Am I correct in thinking this can't work because the ISO-8601 date that forms the key can't be a duplicate?

Comment: I think the original poster wants to only group the events when there are 3 or more that have the same date.

Comment: @depperm I only wish to group them when there are 3 or more events with the same date.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution will be to:

1. First find the count of each individual ISO-8601 date and output that count into an object you can refer to in the next step
2. Group those events that have a count `>2` and add as individual rows those that appear only once.

To get the counts:

```
const countDates = (events) => {
  let dateCounts = {};
  
  for (let i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
    if (!dateCounts[date]) {
      dateCounts[date] = 1;
    } else {
      dateCounts[date]++;
    }
  }
  
  return dateCounts;
}
const dateCounts = countDates(events)
```

If you're storing the results in an object, you will need to use a key other than the date because(as you have written) you can't use the same key for two different properties in an object.

It makes more sense to me to group them as an array of arrays containing one or more events.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I like your approach but I'm struggling to put it into action. The `countDates` works great and I can obviously reference it when reducing the array by using something like `if (dateCounts[date] > 2) { /* Push to array */ } else { /* Create new array and push to that */ }`. However, I'm struggling with how to add these as individual rows? Is there any chance you could show me an example of how you might group them as an array or arrays as you mentioned? Thanks very much!